# Create form select from object containing values

Tags: javascript, forms, object, select, iteration

I have such an object :

```
var options = {1: 'Running', 2: 'Falling', 3: 'Collapsing wall', 
        4: (...)};
```

I'd like to create form's select element with ooptions taken from this object, so something like that (code I tried which is not working, but you can get the idea) :

```
html = '<form action="" ><select name="block-action"><option>-------</option>';
for(k in obj){
    html += '<option value="'+k+'">'+obj[k]+'</option>'
}
html += '</select></form>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var html = []; // <-- make an array

//push the first bits of text onto it
html.push('<form action="" ><select name="block-action"><option>-------</option>');

//here's where we dynamically use the object. You were close! You used the wrong variable name, obj vs. options
for(k in options){
    html.push('<option value="'+k+'">',options[k],'</option>');
}

//and wrap up the html tags you opened to start
html.push('</select></form>');

//use html.join(''); to spit out the text
```

Generally string concats (where you add two strings together, like in your example) are much slower than pushing values onto an array and then joining them. I'd suggest that habit for you.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I can see is that your variable referencing the object is called `options`, but you're using the variable name `obj` instead.

Works for me after that one change.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/X66Su/1/

this:

```
var options = {1: 'Running', 2: 'Falling', 3: 'Collapsing wall', 
    4: (...)};
```

should be:

```
var obj = {1: 'Running', 2: 'Falling', 3: 'Collapsing wall', 
    4: (...)};
```

Comment: @down-voter: Care to explain why? How is this answer incorrect?

Comment: damn, I was trying this in console and wasn't working. Now works like a charm. Thanks :)

Comment: I've been nuked down too, what's the deal? I think we both provided valid answers :-/